# How to merge the lines in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

Consider the following curves:

```
Bound1temp = 
  RegionPlot[
   10^13*10^(2 y)*(10^x/90)^4*Sqrt[1 - 10^(2 x)/90^2.] >= 1, {x, 
    Log10[0.01], Log10[90]}, {y, -11, 0}];
Bound1 = {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[
    Flatten[Cases[Normal@Bound1temp, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
Bound2temp = 
  RegionPlot[
   10^20*10^(2 y)*Sqrt[
     1 - 10^(4 x)/6^4.] (Exp[-10^7.*10^(6*x)*10^(2*y)] - 
       Exp[-(10^7 + 10)*10^(6*x)*10^(2*y)]) >= 1, {x, Log10[0.01], 
    Log10[6.]}, {y, -11, 0}];
Bound2 = {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[
    Flatten[Cases[Normal@Bound2temp, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
ListLogLogPlot[{Bound1, Bound2}]
```

[image]

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to merge them such that their intersection would be removed, i.e. to get the following red line?

**Added**

Let us assume that we have only `Bound1` and `Bound2`, but not the underlying functions/conditions used to obtain them.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pred1 = 10^13*10^(2 y)*(10^x/90)^4*Sqrt[1 - 10^(2 x)/90^2.] >= 1;

pred2 = 10^20*10^(2 y)*
    Sqrt[1 - 10^(4 x)/6^4.] (Exp[-10^7.*10^(6*x)*10^(2*y)] - 
      Exp[-(10^7 + 10)*10^(6*x)*10^(2*y)]) >= 1;


rp12 = RegionPlot[Or[pred1, pred2], {x, Log10[0.01], Log10[90]}, {y, -11, 0}];

bound12 = Cases[Normal @ rp12, Line[x_] :> 10^x, All];


ListLogLogPlot @ bound12
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"what to do if Bound1 and Bound2 are pre-generated, i.e., I do not have access to the initial functions used to extract the contours?"***

```
lllp = ListLogLogPlot[{Bound1, Bound2}];

boundaryline =  RegionBoundary[
   RegionUnion @@ Cases[lllp, Point[x_] :> Polygon[x], All]];

Show[lllp, Prolog -> 
  {AbsoluteThickness[10],JoinForm["Round"], Green, boundaryline}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But what to do if `Bound1` and `Bound2` are pre-generated, i.e., I do not have access to the initial functions used to extract the contours?

Comment: please see the update.